# How to register more than 1 event observer in config.xml

Tags: magento-1.9, module, extensions, event-observer, configuration

How to register more than 1 event observer in config.xml
If called methods are in same class & file.

- When using both observer seprately(registering them seprately) both are working. But when both are enabled can't complete checkout process. After selecting payment information continue buton not working in rwd theme.
- first observer is doing something when payment made successfully. And second observer is printing some text before page load. When using both seprately both are working fine. But when using both at once. Second observer is printing text before body load as it should do. But checkout process can't complete so i don't know second will do work as it should do or not.
- when i disable my module checkout is working. Even 1 remove 1 observer registry from config.xml then checkout is also working.

  ```
    <events>            
        <checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>
              <observers>
                  <Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer_customFunction>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer</class>
                      <method>customFunction</method>
                  </Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer_customFunction>
              </observers>
         </checkout_onepage_controller_success_action>


         <controller_action_layout_load_before>
              <observers>
                  <Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer_cancelorder>
                      <type>singleton</type>
                      <class>Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer</class>
                      <method>smsntf_cancel_order</method>
                  </Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer_cancelorder>
              </observers>
         </controller_action_layout_load_before>
      </events>
  ```

Observer.php

```
<?php
class Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer
{
    public function customFunction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        if(Mage::getStoreConfig('testsection/smsntf/Smsntf_module_activation')){
      //  $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
         //here you can add your custom code
        $layout = Mage::app()->getLayout();

    //IF{ //its working now if is working now

        $messageBlock = $layout->createBlock('core/template', 'smsntf_test');
        $messageBlock->setTemplate('smsntf/red/event_observer/event_observer.phtml');
        $layout->getBlock('before_body_end')->append($messageBlock);

    //}ELSE{
//      $layout->getUpdate()->addHandle('custom_layout_handle'); //refrencing here layout.xml handle
    //}
//      $footer = $layout->getBlock('before_body_end');
//      $footer->setCacheKey(sha1($footer->getCacheKey() . '-payment-message'));


        //NOW GETTING ORDER ID AND OTHER ORDER DETAIL
            $orderIds = $observer->getData('order_ids');

        //  $order     = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($_orderId);
         // $customer  = Mage::getModel('customer/customer')->load($order->getData('customer_id'));
            $orderIds = $observer->getData('order_ids');
        //  foreach($orderIds as $_orderId){
            $order     = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load($orderIds);

    //      print_r($order ->getdata('grand_total'));
    //      print_r($order ->getdata());
        //   }
        //NOW GETTING ORDER ID AND OTHER ORDER DETAIL
        $message_for_send = Mage::getStoreConfig('testsection/smsntf/Smsntf_text_field_msg');
        $http_url = Mage::getStoreConfig('testsection/smsntf/Smsntf_text_field_api_calling_url');
        $arr_params = array('Smsntf_text_field_authkey', 'Smsntf_text_field_mobile', 'Smsntf_text_field_senderid', 'Smsntf_text_field_routeid', 'Smsntf_text_field_additional', 'Smsntf_text_field_additional', 'Smsntf_text_field_additional1', 'Smsntf_text_field_additional2', 'Smsntf_text_field_additional3', 'Smsntf_text_field_additional4');

        //replaceing %O% with Order Number
        $message_for_send = str_replace('%O%',100000000+intval($orderIds[0]),$message_for_send);

        //replaceing %N% with Mobile Number
        $message_for_send = str_replace('%N%',$order->getdata('customer_firstname'),$message_for_send);

        //replaceing %A% with Grand Total
        $message_for_send = str_replace('%A%',$order->getdata('grand_total'),$message_for_send);

        $http_url .='?'. Mage::getStoreConfig('testsection/smsntf/Smsntf_text_field_Msg_prm').'='.urlencode($message_for_send);
        for($a=0; $a<sizeof($arr_params); $a++){
            if(trim(Mage::getStoreConfig('testsection/smsntf/'.$arr_params[$a]))!=''){
                if(trim($arr_params[$a])!='Smsntf_text_field_mobile')
                    $http_url .= '&'.Mage::getStoreConfig('testsection/smsntf/'.$arr_params[$a]);
                else
                    $http_url .= '&'.Mage::getStoreConfig('testsection/smsntf/'.$arr_params[$a]).'='.$order->getBillingAddress()->getData('telephone');

            }       
        }
    //  echo $http_url;
        //printing system->configuration inputs value
        //      echo Mage::getStoreConfig('testsection/smsntf/active');
                $this->send_sms($http_url);

        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function send_sms($feed_url/*, $rauth_key, $amobile, $hmsg, $uid, $lid, $content_type*/){
        $mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
        require_once $mageFilename;
        umask(0);
        Mage::app();

        $curl = new Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl();
        $curl->setConfig(array(
               'timeout'   => 30 
        ));
    //  $feed_url = 'http://sms.vtechnologies4u.in/rest/services/sendSMS/sendGroupSms?AUTH_KEY=48cdfa49d561561cb65dc5175c3aea&mobileNos=7080557519&message=now+its+working_ninee_step&senderId=Vtechn&routeId=1&smsContentType=english';
    //  $feed_url = 'http://sms.vtechnologies4u.in/rest/services/sendSMS/sendGroupSms?AUTH_KEY='.$rauth_key.'&mobileNos='.$amobile.'&message='.$hmsg.'&senderId='.$uid.'&routeId='.$lid.'&smsContentType='.$content_type;

        $curl->write(Zend_Http_Client::GET, $feed_url, '1.0');
        $data = $curl->read();
        if ($data === false) {
           return false;
        }
        $data = preg_split('/^r?$/m', $data, 2);
        $data = trim($data[1]);
        $curl->close();

        try {
            //  $xml  = new SimpleXMLElement($data);
            //  Parse the XML FEED and output the data
        //  echo "Connection done successfully";
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
        //   echo $e->getMessage();
        }
    }

    public function smsntf_cancel_order(){
        echo "i will visile every time befoe page load";
    }
}
```

Comment: Is it not working?

Comment: when i try same. checout not working properly

Comment: Check i have posted an answer

Comment: Please explain, what "not working properly" means. If you can't explain it, this debugging guide should help you: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/428/fundamentals-for-debugging-a-magento-store - also try to narrow it down, i.e. remove the working observer and maybe more, until you have a minimal reproducible example. Your problem is *not* that you have defined two observers.

Comment: i update the question again it was not showing fully its was just showing 1 observer in question. even i was write both thier i think any format problem. please take a look and tell me.

Comment: Try removing echo statement from your `smsntf_cancel_order` function and use some kind of logging instead that doesn't affect the output being sent via the Magento application.

Comment: thanks its worked. But can you tell me how to pass data from observer to layout page? using handlers

Comment: Giver your this comment as answer so i will accept it and other people can get help also

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try removing echo statement from your `smsntf_cancel_order` function and use some kind of logging instead that doesn't affect the output being sent via the Magento application.

Reason will be, at checkout, controllers send ajax response, but your echo statements are messing up with the response being sent.

Comment: Thanks prateek. few people can't understand what i want to say. And give a downvote to my question.

Answer (score 1):

The observer identifier, in your case it's the tag `Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer` right after the `observers` tag must be different for each observer you want to create, that's basically it.

Comment: other things are right?

Comment: yes the rest is ok

Comment: you means second time i should not use observers tag? can i use any tag ?

Comment: no you should use a different identifier. Example the first time you can use `<Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer>` and the second time it must be different, for example: `<Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer_2>`

Comment: it must be different i understand. but can i use anything?

Comment: yes as long as it is a different identifier everytime

Comment: can i use first time this <Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Rahul> for my this module ?

Comment: Again, you have to use a different identifier **per observer** so <Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer> for the first one and <Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Rahul> for the second one for example

Comment: you mean prefixing this is important <Barcatsia_Smsntf_Model_Observer>

Comment: it only has to be different for each *event*, because the XML structure gets merged. I don't see any errors in he shown code

Comment: i had update my question. actually i am using this. but its not working perfectly. its disturb my checkout. And checout process cant complete

Comment: @fschmengler is right i used many event  with same xml structure only the method is different. they are running without any problem. so this is not issue.

Comment: i update the question again it was not showing fully its was just showing 1 observer in question. even i was write both thier i think any format problem. please take a look and tell me.